# Как выбрать НЕ уникальный элементы массива

Tags: ruby

Необходимо выбрать по одному элементу не уникальных значений массива. Пример:

```
arr = [1, 2 ,2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
```

должно вернуть

```
arr1 = [2, 3]
```

Есть некий анти `uniq` метод?

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать множество (`Set`), чтобы в процессе обхода выяснять:

1. не встречался ли элемент ранее
2. не попал ли он уже в результат ранее

Чтобы максимально сократить записи, можно использовать [метод `Set#add?`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-add-3F), совмещающий в себе добавление нового элемента (`Set#add`) и проверку на то, не существовал ли он там уже (`Set#include?`, с отрицанием; если элемент уже был, `add?` вернёт `nil`):

```
require "set"
known    = Set.new # Для п. 1
non_uniq = Set.new # Для п. 2
arr.select { |e| !known.add?(e) && non_uniq.add?(e) }
```

В двух словах, алгоритм представляет собой: "выбрать элементы, которые не удалось добавить в `known` (которые там уже есть), но удалось добавить в `non_uniq`". В отличие от решения с `count`, этот алгоритм не делает полного обхода исходного массива для подсчёта на каждой итерации.

По итогам результат будет не только возвращён, но будет также в `non_uniq`, но не в форме массива, а в форме множества.

Answer (score 1):

Вот как я это решил

```
arr.select{ |i| arr.count(i) > 1 }.uniq
```